# Inserir período de tempo em banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estive pensando aqui... Existe algum método de inserir no banco de dados várias datas ao mesmo tempo?

Por exemplo um evento que comece dia 03/02 e vá até dia 07/02. Como inserir esse intervalo no MySQL para que todos os dias entre 03 e 07 uma publicação permaneça ativa em um site, por assim dizer?

Desde já agradeço

Abraços

Comment: Está um pouco confusa, mas, basicamente quer a geração de registros entre essas duas datas?, Por acaso tem algum código?

Comment: Não é só armazenar "inicio" e "fim" em dois campos datetime?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, vamos a resposta: Sim e não. Por quê? Sim, pois existe maneiras de se resolver seu problema, de forma a armazenar duas datas, uma referente ao início de um evento temporal, outra referente ao seu término. Não, pois não é possível fazer isso em apenas uma coluna no seu banco de dados (isso nem faz tanto sentido). Ou seja, para armazenarmos um *range* de datas, temos que criar duas colunas na tabela, uma para armazenar o início, outra para o término.

Para fins justificar os exemplos posteriores, vamos considerar uma tabela no seguinte formato:

```
create table eventos (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  nome varchar(255),
  inicio date,
  fim date
);
```

Uma tabela básica, com *id* único alto incrementado, um *nome* no formato texto e dois campos do tipo *date*, *inicio* e *fim*, para armazenar o início e o fim de cada evento, como deve imaginar. Agora vamos popular esta tabela com alguns registros básicos:

```
insert into eventos (nome, inicio, fim) values ('Carnaval',  '2017-02-24', '2017-02-28');
insert into eventos (nome, inicio, fim) values ('Férias',    '2017-01-01', '2017-02-28');
insert into eventos (nome, inicio, fim) values ('Foo',       '2017-02-03', '2017-02-07');
insert into eventos (nome, inicio, fim) values ('Hoje',      '2017-02-01', '2017-02-01');
insert into eventos (nome, inicio, fim) values ('Reveillon', '2016-12-31', '2017-01-01');
```

Agora queremos descobrir quais são os eventos que estão acontecendo em um determinado dia, correto? Vamos supor que retornar os eventos no dia 04/02/2017. Basta executarmos a seguinte instrução:

```
select id, nome from eventos where inicio <= "2017-02-04" and fim >= "2017-02-04";
```

> Pode-se, alternativamente, utilizar `where "2017-02-04" between inicio and fim` para produzir o mesmo resultado, deixando a instrução mais legível.

Basicamente estamos dizendo ao SQL: Da tabela `eventos`, retorne-me os valores de `id` e `nome` dos eventos com data de início menor que (anterior à) 04/02/2017 e data de término maior que (posterior à) 04/02/2017.

O resultado? É o mostrado abaixo:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | nome                |
+----+---------------------+
| 2  | Férias              |
+----+---------------------+
| 3  | Foo                 |
+----+---------------------+
```

> O signal de igual nas comparações em *where* tem como finalidade incluir o dia buscado no *range* desejado.

Já resolvemos o problema? Sim, mas que tal deixar mais dinâmico?

Podemos alterar a instrução SQL de forma que ela sempre busque os eventos do dia atual, sem que tenhamos que identificar o dia através de uma linguagem externa. Podemos fazer isso através do comando [`curdate()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp), como abaixo:

```
select id, nome from eventos where inicio <= curdate() and fim >= curdate();
```

> Pode-se, alternativamente, utilizar `where curdate() between inicio and fim` para produzir o mesmo resultado, deixando a instrução mais legível.

Desta forma, o resultado será, para hoje, dia 01/02/2017, o seguinte:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | nome                |
+----+---------------------+
| 2  | Férias              |
+----+---------------------+
| 4  | Hoje                |
+----+---------------------+
```

Legal, mas que tal buscarmos todos os eventos que já se encerraram? Sem problemas.

```
select id, nome from eventos where fim < curdate();
```

Resultando em:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | nome                |
+----+---------------------+
| 5  | Reveillon           |
+----+---------------------+
```

Os eventos futuros? Mesma ideia.

```
select id, nome from eventos where inicio > curdate();
```

Resultando em:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | nome                |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | Carnaval            |
+----+---------------------+
| 4  | Foo                 |
+----+---------------------+
```

> Lembrando que os resultados apresentados nas últimas três intruções, que envolvem o uso da função `curdate()` varia conforme o dia que está sendo executada. Desta forma, foi apresentado os resultados referentes ao dia 01/02/2017.

Você ainda pode conferir todas as instruções apresentadas aqui em funcionamento [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed1ed/3). Os resultados de cada instrução são apresentados em tabelas distintas, na parte inferior da página.